# Connect Redis using node JS in Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, redis

I am trying to connect to redis in linux using node js as below

`var redis = require('redis');`

But, getting the error as below. 
I have redis-2.4.17 installed in linux and the path is /home/masadmin/redis-2.4.17/src
Kindly help on how to connect to redis using node in linux.

```
module.js:340
    throw err;

          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'redis'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/masadmin/Vinod/prapprRedisLoad.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the Node.js Redis module for your application? `npm install redis` (in the same directory as your application) will install it. Check out [this screencast](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/4-packages-and-npm) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. Regret my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error after Node.js Redis module has been installed.
I've fixed it (error) after changing NODE_PATH environment variable:

```
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:<YOUR_NODE.JS_HOME>/node_modules
```